# Access on an element from another window

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, label

I don't know why it's not working with any thread I already found here about this problem. I just want to get access on a Label from another window. So here are the MainWindow

```
Public Class MainWindow
    Private WithEvents _popUpBox As NewCompany
    Private Sub Button_NewGame_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button_NewGame.Click
        If _popUpBox Is Nothing Then
            _popUpBox = New NewCompany
            _popUpBox.ShowDialog()
        Else
            _popUpBox.Activate()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

and the NewCompany/popUpBox

```
Public Class NewCompany
    Private Sub Button_Confirm_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button_Confirm.Click
        MainWindow.Label_Company.Content = "Some Company"
    End Sub
End Class
```

I know that it's MVVM and it's completely different to Windows Forms. So maybe someone can help me with this small example.

So How can I change the content of this Label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before opening PopupBox, set `Owner` to be `MainWindow` and you can access it from popup window using Owner property.

*MainWindow*

```
_popUpBox = New NewCompany
_popUpBox.Owner = Me
_popUpBox.ShowDialog()
```

*Popup window*

```
DirectCast(Owner, MainWindow).Label_Company.Content = "Some Company"
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error right here: ((MainWindow)Owner).Label_Company.Content = "Some Company"

Comment: You need to typecast Owner to MainWindow. I posted the syntax of C#. How you typecast in VB.Net?

Comment: I have update answer with VB.Net version. Hope that will help.